# EPPlus6.0 CollapseChildren doesn't collapse my rows

Tags: epplus

I upgraded from EPPlus4.0 to 6.0 and having trouble with collapsing rows in excel sheets.

Collapsing a row in the 4.0 was like this

```
worksheet.Row(row).Collapsed = true;
```

But it's changed in the 6.0 and I'm trying to achieve the collapse using CollapseChildren() method but failing.
`worksheet.Cells[row, 1].EntireRow.CollapseChildren();` 
I expect the CollapseChildren() will collapse the row above or below but neither happens.

I haven't set the OutLineSummaryBelow property.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right about needing to use CollapseChildren.

There's been some other changes between 4.0 and 6.0
You need to group things together before collapsing children [as seen on the Epplus Wiki](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Grouping-and-Ungrouping-Rows-and-Columns).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).